# Error in code in R: target of assignment expands to non-language object

Tags: r, variable-assignment, target

I'm trying to make a loop in R to extract the columns of an xts dataframe, and create 49 different df. However when i try to run it i get  the error:
target of assignment expands to non-language object

p_15_19 is the original xts file with 50 columns (first column is the date) and basically i want to make 49 new files with names:

v1_15_19

v2_15_19

.

.

v49_15_19

```
for(i in 1:49) {
  assign(paste("v",i,"_15_19",sep=""))<-p_15_19[,c(i+1)]
}
```

Comment: Forget `assign`, learn to use lists as containers for multiple objects in loops.

Comment: Check with the help page. It's `assign(var_name, data)`, not what you have.

Answer (score 2):

If you truely want to do this, the problem is in your `assign(...1) <- ...2` code (...1 being first arguments and ...2 being the second arguments). This problem is easily solved by following the documentation available by executing `help(assign)` and reading the documentation. The correct formulation is simply `assign(...1, ...2)` where `...1` would be the name of the variable and `...2` is the value of the variable.

**However!** this is highly inefficient, and assuming you want to perform similar code following this, you are more likely looking for `list` objects.

```
dfs <- vector("list", 49)
#name the list of data.frames
names(dfs) <- paste0("v", 1:49, "_15_19")
for(i in 1:49)
    dfs[[i]] <- p_15_19[, i+1]
```

In `dfs` you now have every sheet in the `xts` file contained at the indices `[[1]], [[2]], ...` and so on. These can also be referenced by name. Assuming they all contain only numeric variables, it is not simpler to perform summary statistics such as `mean` `median` etc. Or more complicated functions. For example using the `lapply` (list-apply) function

```
#calculate mean of each sheet and remove missing values.
lapply(dfs, mean, na.omit = TRUE)
```